# Is there a way for a adobe air application to ask for to be run as with administrator privileges when it runs?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe

I have an application that needs to run at administrator privileges. Is there a way to force a uac prompt when the application starts in adobe air?

I am running another exe from inside my application and if I run my application as a admin then it will run the exe with out popping up the uac prompt but if i don't i get a uac prompt every single time i run the exe inside the application witch could happen a lot and gets old very fast.

Comment: pretty sure the answer is no, but the end user in windows can tell a program to launch with admin (right click an executable and go to properties, then go to the "compatibility" tab)

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the another application with a bat file with:

```
 runas /user:Administrator anotherApp.exe
```